# put the objectives of different variable in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, for-loop

I MIP model in gurobi I value the variables and get their objectives. this happened in for loop and by value variable upper and lower bound.

But now I want to get all of the solution in dictionary. when I write dictionary it only get one solution.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry can't understand you. Can you rephrase what you are trying to ask?

Comment: @Ralf in my mathematical model I have a binary variable that I value it in different indexes and get the model objective in all situations. (for j in N:      x[(1,0,j)].lb = 1       x[(1,0,j)].ub = 1). it is obvious that for each variable that become 1 we have a unique objective. I want to bring all these objectives in a dictionary. (d = {}      for j in J:     d[(1,0,j)] = obj). but it does not work and does not get me the dict.